# TabBar disappears when programatic segue

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I want to segue to a new ViewController programatically but when I do my tabBar disappears.

```
 if user == usernameStored && pass == passwordStored{
        print("Good")
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "home")
        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)



    }
```

Comment: Is that view controller linked to tab bar?

Comment: Yes its on the main.storyboard

Comment: can you show your storyboard image ?

Comment: Just added it @TusharSharma

Comment: You're presenting a view controller. This is an expected behavior.

Comment: So what should I do? @LucaD'Alberti

Comment: Depends on your design. The options are: add a child view controller or push a new view controller in order to keep the tab bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, this is not `segue` by programmatically. You actually `present` a `viewController` on top of whatever you have. Therefore the `tabBarController` is cover.

To use `segue` in code, it should be something like this. - `homeSegueID` is the `identifier` you give when you created the `segue` in storyboard.

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "homeSegueID", sender: nil)
```

If you just want to do it programatically without `segue`, you could do this instead. (This assume your current `ViewController` is in a `UINavigationController` stack.

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is the navigation controller wrapping your view controllers a tab bar controller, or did you just add the tab bar to your view controller?  This is what you should be doing:

[image: Tab Bar Controller]